# how to assert there is (or not) an object in a list with a given enum as an attribute?

Tags: java, assert

If a `class` is defined as

```
public class MyClass {
    private long id;
    private MyEnum myEnum;
    // getter and setters
}
```

and `MyEnumClass` is defined as

```
public enum MyEnum {
    VALUE_A, VALUE_B, VALUE_C;
}
```

How could a test make sure a `List<MyClass>` does not contain any instance of `MyClass` where `MyClass`.`enum` is, for instance, `VALUE_C`?

Comment: How about trying to find such an element (by iteration and checking the value)? Then make your test expect that no such element can be found, e.g. by checking some boolean (expect false), counter (expect 0) or `Optional` (expect `isPresent()` to return false).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One-liner solution using stream API:

```
assert(list.stream().noneMatch(element -> MyEnum.VALUE_C.equals(element.getEnum())));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check it this way:

```
boolean result = myClassList.stream().map(MyClass::getMyEnum).noneMatch(MyEnum.VALUE_C::equals);
```